# Does not show products with the "Product Category" widget

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget

In my theme, on the WooCommerce archive page, the code to display products:

```
<?php
    if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
         *
         * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

        woocommerce_product_loop_start();

        if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
                 *
                 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' ); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            }
        } else {
            do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
        }

        woocommerce_product_loop_end();

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
         */

        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );

        } else {
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
         *
         * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
    }

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */

    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */

    // do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

I needed to show each category with its products. For example:

Category 1

product 1 product 2 product 3

Category 2

product 1 product 2 product 3

For this, I used the new code:

```
<?php
foreach( get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' ) ) as $category ) :
    $products_loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',

        'showposts' => -1,

        'tax_query' => array_merge( array(
            'relation'  => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'terms'    => array( $category->term_id ),
                'field'   => 'term_id'
            )
        ), WC()->query->get_tax_query() ),

        'meta_query' => array_merge( array(

            // You can optionally add extra meta queries here

        ), WC()->query->get_meta_query() )
    ) );

?>
    <h2 class="category-title"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>

    <?php
    while ( $products_loop->have_posts() ) {
        $products_loop->the_post();
        /**
         * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
         *
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But after the change, the standard WooCommerce "Product Category" widget stopped working for me. When you select a specific category in the widget, only the link in the browser changes, and the products of this category themselves do not appear. Shows all store products.

How can I combine these two code options so that the widget works correctly?